# Django Search Form Errors When Adding to_form_field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Whenever I try to add to_form_field to subject and membership form fields, I get the following errors:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Programming'
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Free'
>
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Programming'.
>
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Free'.

**URL without to_form_name:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?name=&min_views=&max_views=&min_date=&max_date=&expertise=&subject=1&membership=1
```

​
**URL with to_form_name:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?name=&min_views=&max_views=&min_date=&max_date=&expertise=&subject=Programming&membership=Free
```

I would like to be able to pass the actual string rather than the number in the URL for SEO purposes. When I leave to_field_name out of forms.py, there is no error and my search form filtering works. But it puts numbers in the URL which is undesirable.

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington  I added the traceback. Please refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `to_field_name` on your `ModelChoiceField`s, so you need to query by the fields that you set for those parameters

```
            if subject_query:
                qs = qs.filter(subject__name=subject_query)
            if membership_query:
                qs = qs.filter(allowed_memberships__membership_type=membership_query)
```

Comment: Perfect that worked! I will have another question coming up shortly regarding sorting using this same code. Stay tuned.